# Upload a photo to a specific album

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I post a photo via the method **startForUploadPhoto**
-> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/protocol/FBGraphUser/#id

But I could not find a way to specify the album name, currently it's **nameOfMyApp's photo**

Is there a way to rename it or should I use the open graph API instead ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The default album has that name. You could always try uploading the photo to an album you previously created and given the name you desire.

See this reference doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.5/class/FBRequest#requestForUploadPhoto%3A

It basically says you can do something like this:

```
FBRequest *photoUploadRequest = [FBRequest requestForUploadPhoto:myPhoto];
photoUploadRequest[@"album"] = albumID;
```

Where "myPhoto" is the UIImage representation of your photo and "albumID" is an existing album ID with your desired album name.